# First NeuroNetwork, troubles(

Tags: neural-network

I've never done neural network development before, but it just so happens that I HAVE to do it before January 23, inclusive, or I will miss a huge number of opportunities. I get a huge bunch of mistakes that I don't know what to do with. Be so kind-correct my code and explain to me what I'm doing wrong) thank You all
UPD code:

```
import numpy as np
def Sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
trn_inp=np.array([[1],[2],[3]])  #Массив 3 на 1. 3  строки и 1 столбец
trn_out=np.array([[1,2,3]]).T #Ожидаемые выходные данные
print("trn_inp now: \n"+str(trn_inp))
print("trn_inp matrix: "+str(np.shape(trn_inp)))
print("trn_out now: \n"+str(trn_out))
print("trn-out matrix: \n"+str(np.shape(trn_out)))
np.random.seed(1)
syn_wei=2*np.random.random((1,1))-1   #Создается массив размером x на y, который заполняется рандомными значениями от -1 до 1
#print(syn_wei)
o=1
for i in range(100):
    print("Try # "+str(o))
    out=Sigmoid(np.dot(trn_inp, syn_wei))
    err=trn_out-out
    adj=np.dot(trn_inp.T,err*(out*(1-out)))
    syn_wei+=adj
    o+=1
    print("=="*10)
    print("New weights: ")
    print(syn_wei)
    print("=="*10)
print("Out after refresh: ")
print(out)
new_inp=np.array([[8,2,3]]).T #Введение нового значения для сравнения
out=Sigmoid(np.dot(new_inp, syn_wei))
print("New out: "+str(out))
print(out)
#out_str="".join(str(x) for x in out)
#print(out_str)
out_flt=0
for k in range(0,len(out)):
    out_flt=out[k]
    #print(out_flt)
    if out_flt==0:
        print("No matches")
    elif out_flt>=0.5:
        print("May have matches")
    elif out_flt>=0.8:
        print("Match")
    else:
        print("ERROR")
#out_flt=float(out_str)
#out_int=int(out_str)
#print("Results for new situation : "+out_str)
```

Comment: Could you please mention, what kind of NN you want to build? Single-layer or multilayer. In addition variables you are using are not clear themselves. It seems you initialize weights with syn_weg, it would be better to write it as weights_initilaization or something. If you want to use NN in your formatted dataset you can use various available packages.

Comment: What do you mean?  I do not know so much about it, so please give me a tip.

Comment: You need to tell us what the problems are and what is the objective of this code, else we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I want to train the network to distinguish numbers from each other.  A matrix with numbers from 0 to 9 is created in trn-inp, and the same numbers are sent to the input for training in trn-out to make the network understand that, for example, I expect that, when comparing 0 elements of both arrays, that is  zero, I will receive a confirmation.  Based on this, I wrote the program.  But, since problems arose at the beginning of training, that is, at the beginning of the second block, then i don't see the point for digging in third block

Comment: What do you mean "problems arose"? Please be specific, do you get errors?

Comment: Yes, i get it. Now i take that error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Утилиты\Sublime Text 3\Projects\EXP_COPY.py", line 19, in <module>
    syn_wei+=adj
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,2)

Comment: I'm did some correctivies with code, but don't know how i can paste it here

Comment: You can always edit your own question (look for the edit link above)

Comment: Redacted, check it pls